# Не работает стрелка возврата активити

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Есть главная активити, в ней фрагмент, который содержит список. Есть кнопка (если важно - снизу кастомная панель, то есть она  не находится в элементах списка и к адаптеру не имеет никакого отношения).

Эта кнопка вызывает следующую активити - всё получается как и ожидалось, кроме того факта, что по стрелке назад он не возвращает на главную активити. Лишь и только на кнопку "назад".

Код вызова новой активити:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        ImageButton sort = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.sort_by);
        sort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),SortBy.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

SortBy class:

```
public class SortBy extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sort_by_activity);
        setToolbar();
    }

    private void setToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.sort_toolbar);

        toolbar.setTitle("Sort by");

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Что упустил, где ошибся?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если позволяет минимальный уровень API то можно ограничиться указанием `android:parentActivityName=".ActivityMain"` в виде атрибута второй активити в манифесте. Если не позволяет, то надо добавить ещё `meta-data` тэг внутрь тэга активити в манифесте:

```
<!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value=".ActivityMain" />
```

Либо повесить программно слушатель нажатий на `toolbar`:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        finish(); //или вызываем нажатие на back: onBackPressed();
    }
});
```